# Google Play Service LeaderBoard

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, leaderboard

I've tried to integrate google play Leaderboard in my android app , i've created a leader board in the googole play console and linked it to the app and added myself as a tester but the app is still **not published** ,

so when i test the app I'm able to logging successfully to play service , but when i hit the leader board button nothing happens ..

is it because the application is not published yet ? how I'm supposed to test it before publishing ?

(i'm using unity game engine and the googleplayservice package in the app)

Thanks in advance